# PayPal PDT like functionaility for Stripe

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

I am planning to use Stripe to accept payments for digital products and want to redirect the (legit) user to a download/thank you page after payment. Until now, I have been using PayPal and its PDT service helped me do just that. Infact, I could do a callback to PayPal from the download page, to confirm that the transaction info was correct, that the order was actually placed and then process the same (did so using the following tutorial:- http://www.paysketch.com/setup-paypal-pdt/)

I have been looking around a lot, but have been unable to find PDT like functionality in Stripe. What way can I implement the same? Following are the primary motives:-

1. User should be redirected to a thank you/download page after payment
2. My script should be able to verify the same from stripe

Please suggest.

Comment: Stripe doesn't offer a hosted payment page, only Stripe Checkout (https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)

Comment: @koopajah I wasn't taking about a separate hosted page. Once the buyer pays through Stripe Checkout and the payment is successful, I'd ideally want to verify the payment and then redirect the user to a download page from my end.